# Why doesn't Lois leave Peter?

Tags: character, family-guy

Throughout Family Guy, Peter does many things that would make any normal person leave their spouse such as

- buying a farm without consulting the rest of the family
- joining a  terrorist group
- buying a motorcycle
- etc.

A few times that this happens, Lois threatens or says that she will leave him if this happens again. And then it does happen again. So why doesn't she leave him?

I'm sure some people are going to say "She's a main character. She can't leave the show!" However, I believe that it could be an interesting episode where they get back together at the end or even the way to end the series.

Now if I can think of this, hasn't Seth? So is there a reason she hasn't divorced him yet, either as a plot point or simply from common sense?

Comment: I'm sorry but you can't just question the entire premise of a show. At best, you'll get opinion-based answers...

Comment: I too think this is possibly too opinion based, but I've added the post-notice rather than closing it, you never know there may be an interview where Seth gives some insight into this.  I wouldn't be surprised however if it gains 5 close votes because as it is written it is going to attract opinion answers.

Comment: Let's not forget the episode where Lois is seduced by Bill Clinton.

Comment: Maybe because its 1. A cartoon and 2. A comedy and has no basis in reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because [it's been done before, to a different degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welcome_Back,_Carter).

> "Welcome Back, Carter" is the third episode of the ninth season of the
>   animated comedy series Family Guy. It originally aired on Fox in the
>   United States on October 10, 2010. The episode follows Peter after he
>   discovers his father-in-law, Carter Pewterschmidt, having an affair
>   with another woman. Deciding to blackmail him, Peter begins taking
>   advantage of his father-in-law's enormous wealth, before accidentally
>   spilling the beans to Carter's wife, Barbara, who divorces him soon
>   after. Peter then becomes Carter's wingman, and helps him in
>   rediscovering his bachelorhood, as he begins navigating through the
>   dating scene.

Carter and Barbara do end up reuniting at the end of the episode.

Family Guy tends to push boundaries and doesn't often (if ever) visit the same topics or storyline, unless they're recurring jokes.